# How can I extract all the data from the Cancer Types Summary Page on CBioPortal at once?

Tags: web-scraping

I would really like to take the data that  would normally be seen by hovering over each column at once.  The graph is an interactive one so its hard to extract all the data at once. I would really like it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you pick a **programming language** that you know fairly well.

Then load the web pages, use a selector to select the desired elements, and output the data in the format you like.

Please begin writing the code, and update your question when you have something working at least partially, so you can ask precisely where you need help